# is running mismatched pairs of RAM sticks likely to cause memtest86 errors?

Tags: memory, memtest86+

I put 4 4GB sticks in my ASUS G53 notebook, and memtest86 is giving me errors. CPU-Z says they're running at 1.50V, CL/tRCD/tRP/tRAS of 9/9/9/24. Unfortunately I'm running twinned pairs, Corsair in slots 1/3 and Micron in slots 2/4, which I hear is bad news (the pairs themselves are supposed to match one another).

Is it conceivable that the problem could still be the mismatched pairs, or does the fact memtest86 shows errors conclusively indicate the problem is a specific piece of hardware (eg a bad stick or a bad mobo slot, or RAM not seated properly)? If I remove one pair and see no errors, I'm wondering if I can be sure that one of those sticks is bad, rather than that those sticks are fine, but they can't be mismatched with another pair. (disassembling to test is a bit of a procedure for this laptop, so I want to minimize how many times I do it)

I assume there's no way to disable certain slots to identify which stick is bad without removing the RAM? I can see no obvious way in memtest86 to test individual sticks.

Comment: Pairs are not required to match, they only do if you want the best possible performance.  If Memtest86+ is giving you any errors at all, and the motherboard or memory controller is not at fault, you should be able to find the bad DIMM individually.  Once you narrow it down to a single pair, test both DIMMs in the pair.  And in general, no, there is no way to disable DIMMs without physically removing the RAM.

Comment: @Breakthrough cool. I assume without a second laptop there's no way to tell whether the motherboard slot is bad or the RAM is bad?

Comment: Most likely neither is bad and it's just a configuration error, a RAM slot that needs to be cleaned, a dirty heatsink, or a  failing fan.

Comment: @jela if you can isolate the failure to a single DIMM and can ensure that it consistently causes errors in Memtest86+, then it's likely that stick of RAM and not the motherboard...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, No.  A followup would be to isolate which stick(1) of memory is giving the errors.  Pairs dont matter at this level of testing.  Sadly, you are going to have to test each individual stick.  I would recommend once you find a known good stick, try it once in all of the slots as well.  Remove the slots as a  possible point of failure, and all that you have left is the memory.